# How to customize LinkedIn button?

Tags: linkedin-api, social-media

I'd like to use my own icon to display a LinkedIn follow button.

This is how I currently display the official follow button:

```
    <script src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="IN/FollowCompany" data-id="accountID" data-counter="none"></script>
```

Comment: have you found a way to do this?

Comment: no, I used my own design and simply linked it to the client's LinkedIn page. That was a year ago, though, maybe there's a way to do it now.

Answer (score 0):

The platform Branding Guidelines cover using LinkedIn materials in the manner you are asking about:

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/branding-guidelines

In the 'Logos For Use By LinkedIn Members' section, you can see that you can create a custom button containing the IN logo, along with text along the lines of 'Follow Us' or 'Follow our Company'.

Just download the IN logo from that page and you should be well on your way.

Comment: Yes, but I want to customize the logo to fit the site's color scheme, which LinkedIn won't allow.

Comment: I think this is not possible. Or you can make your own based on the original. I don't know sorry

Comment: you can create a a href link with your own styles and then insert this as the link: https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=(your url will go here)

Answer (score 0):

**LinkedIn Customize button onclick function you can call linked in login function**

```
    <!-- language: lang-html -->

        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
            api_key: Your App Key //**add your linkedIn aap key here**
            authorize: true
        </script>    

         //**create your customized linkedIn button with css**
        <div id="wLinkedIn"> 
         // **use onLinkedInLoad onclick function in customized button** 
         <a href="#" onclick="onLinkedInLoad();">
          <span id="icon-bg"><i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></span>
          <span id="icon-label-bg">Login with LinkedIn</span>
         </a>
        </div>

    <!-- language: lang-js -->

        // ----------------------------LinkedIn Sdk---------------------

        function onLinkedInLoad() { 
            IN.UI.Authorize().place();
       // **call onLinkedInLogin on click of button**
            IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", function () { onLinkedInLogin(); }); 

            //IN.Event.on(IN, "logout", function () { onLinkedInLogout(); });
        }

        function onLinkedInLogin() {
            //alert('logged in');
       //**get all user data from linked in plugin**
            IN.API.Raw("/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,emailAddress)format=json").result(function (data)
         {  
                console.log(data);

                var profileData = data;
                LinkedInFName = profileData.firstName;
                LinkedInLName = profileData.lastName;
                LinkedInEmail = profileData.emailAddress;
                LinkedInId = profileData.id;
                //alert("LinkedInFName : " + LinkedInFName);

                GetLinkedinLoginDetails(LinkedInEmail, LinkedInId)
            }).error(function (error) {
                console.log('Error : ' + error);
            });
        }

        function onSuccess(data) {

        }
```